# What is the sum of x+y?

Tags: polynomials, quadratics, radicals

Can someone please help me in solving this problem.

if $\sqrt{x} + \sqrt{y} = 5+2\sqrt{6}$, then $x + y$ is equal to

(a) $2\sqrt{6}$

(b)  $5-2\sqrt{6}$

(c)  $5$

(d)  $2\sqrt{6}$

Comment: Could be any of them. Why is a) and d) the same

Comment: most obvious choices for $x, y$ are $25, 24$

Comment: I think you are missing some necessary information here.

Comment: if RHS is pow(5+2\sqrt{6}, 2) then what will the solution?

Comment: $\sqrt{x}+\sqrt y=(\text{positive constant})$ allows infinitely many values for $x+y$

Answer (score 1):

If we trust in the strict equality then

$$\sqrt{x} + \sqrt{y} = 5 + 2\sqrt{6}$$

might mean

$$\sqrt{x} = 5 \to x = 25$$

$$\sqrt{y} = 2\sqrt{6}\to y = 24$$

Hence

$$x + y = 25 + 24 = 49 = \text{none of them}$$

Otherwise, just write the equation

$$\sqrt{x} + \sqrt{y} = 5 + 2\sqrt{6}$$

Square it and try to get a solution, which be, by the way, not unique since one parameter is free (either $x$ or $y$).

Comment: If I assume, there is a printing mistake in text book and the question is altered, RHS is pow(5+2 sqrt{6}, 2) then what will the solution?

Comment: @Raman It's the same.. even if it's powered, you have infinite solutions because you have two different variables, not a unique one...